# Singleton Tuple Equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I gather that mathematicians distinguish between sets of a single element and the element itself, that is $\forall x,\ x \ne \{x\}$.

However, in regard to tuples, is it true that $\forall x,\ x = (x)$?

$*$  Where $(x)$ is the singleton tuple with element $x$.

Comment: How do you define $(x)$?

Comment: I would define $(x)$ as the singleton tuple with element $x$, just as I would define $()$ as the empty tuple, without any element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One standard set theoretic definition of tuples is

$$(a) := \{ a \}, \quad (a, b) := \{ a, \{ a, b \} \}, \quad (a, b, c) := \{ a, \{ a, b \}, \{ a, b, c \} \}, \quad \text{ etc.}$$

If this is the definition you are using, then formally $x \neq (x)$.

---

*Added:*

There's an important distinction between $x$ and $(x)$ in vector spaces. For example, $\mathbb R$ over itself is a vector space and we often write the vector space as $\mathbb R^1$. The members of $\mathbb R^1$  are $(x)$ for any $x \in \mathbb R$. Scalar multiplication is defined by

$$a(x) := (ax)$$

which means of course that $x(x) = (x^2)$.

Casually people often write members of $\mathbb R^1$ as just $x$. But as I hope the example shows, there is a difference between $x$ the member of the field $\mathbb R$ and $(x)$ the member of the vector space $\mathbb R^1$.

Comment: I'm in the initial stages of creating a programming language in which I'm thinking to represent nothing as $()$, and to treat individual singleton tuples interchangeably with the elements they contain.

Can you think of any more conceptual differences between $(x)$ and $x$?

Comment: See added comment above

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a reasonable definition of a $1$-tuple $(x)$ would be just the set $\{x\}$. Then it reduces to your first comment on $x\neq \{x\}$.

A $2$-tuple $(x,y)$ is the same as an ordered pair, but when you have a tuple of just one element, the ordering doesn't matter.